# can form Contain another form in winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

i want to make one form contain another form ;
For the sake of browsing different sub-forms in the same Parent Form using parent controls .

Comment: That could be done with a TabControl, pretty much like google chrome or I.E 9 does. I recommend against MDI, those interfaces are pretty much deprecated nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to set the parent form property

`IsMdiContainer = true ;`

and set child forms with

```
childForm.MdiParent = parentForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TabControl to group different controls together, however if you REALLY need to have a subform, you can use MDI forms.

This is a tabcontrol:

[image]

It basically has a groupbox for each individual tab, so you can add and remove as you please.

From the docs for tabcontrol:

> A TabControl contains tab pages, which are represented by TabPage
>   objects that you add through the TabPages property. The order of tab
>   pages in this collection reflects the order the tabs appear in the
>   control. The user can change the current TabPage by clicking one of
>   the tabs in the control.

And MDI:

> Multiple-document interface (MDI) applications allow you to display
>   multiple documents at the same time, with each document displayed in
>   its own window. MDI applications often have a Window menu item with
>   submenus for switching between windows or documents.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for TabControl in C#. This allows to to browse through different tabs in the same parent form. You may refer to [TabControl in C#](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tabcontrol) for more information.

Hope this helps.